# Is there an app that translates audio from one language into another?

Tags: windows-7, audio, language, translation

I have a video in French, that I want to translate the audio into English. It doesn't have to be perfect. I already understand what's going on in the video but a simple translation like Google's text translation would be pretty helpful.

I can extract the audio separately and run it through a software, which is what I am expecting. So this would be suffice. I don't think there are software that could translate it in real time while the video is playing.

Comment: Real time speech to text *and* translation is quite a tall order! For those who might search on your behalf, do you have an OS preference?

Comment: Win7, but I don't really need real-time translation. Just an app that will take an audio file as an input and output a new audio file that's translated from language A to language B. This should already have been done before, right?

Comment: You should work for Microsoft Research! ;)

Comment: The doctors in the hospital in my town (Trondheim) use a voice recognition software to author notes. The problem is, the software has to be trained up to recognize a voice and it's problematic even then, according to one doctor. I did inquire what software they were using, but he wasn't able to find the name of the application. So perhaps searching for voice recognition software would help, although frankly I think the technology is not there yet to make automatic translations.

Comment: "Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."